# Transfer Date from DataGridView to Crystal Reports VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime, crystal-reports, report

When I use these codes `Dim inDate As String = CStr(dgr.Cells(0).Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))`. The error says the conversion from string "MM-dd-yyyy" to type integer is not valid. But when I use these codes `Dim inDate As String = CStr(dgr.Cells(0).Value`. It displays the date from GridView but with a time format. I only want to display the date, not the datetime. To transfer data from grid view to crystal reports. I used DataSet and DataTable. The data type of date columns from the table is a string. These are my full code.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim report1 As New payslip
        Try
            Dim ds As New DataSet1
            Dim ms As New MemoryStream
            CompanyLogo_Picture.Image.Save(ms, CompanyLogo_Picture.Image.RawFormat)
            Dim byt() As Byte = ms.ToArray
            ds.DataTable1.Rows.Add(byt)
            For Each dgr As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView3.Rows
                Dim inDate As String = CStr(dgr.Cells(0).Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
                Dim inTime As TimeSpan = dgr.Cells(1).Value
                Dim outDate As String = CStr(dgr.Cells(2).Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))
                Dim outTime As TimeSpan = dgr.Cells(3).Value
                ds.DataTable2.Rows.Add(inDate, inTime, outDate, outTime)
            Next
            report1.SetDataSource(ds)
            report1.SetParameterValue("employeeName", TextBox6.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("companyName", CompanyName_Label.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("companyAddress", CompanyAddress_Label.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("dateFrom", DateTimePicker1.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("dateTo", DateTimePicker2.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("dailyRate", payslip_dailyRate.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("totalDays", payslip_totalDays.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("mealAllowance", payslip_mealAllowance.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("transportationAllowance", payslip_transpoAllowance.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("medicalAllowance", payslip_medicalAllowance.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("grossPay", payslip_grossPay.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("SSS", payslip_sss.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("philHealth", payslip_philhealth.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("pagibig", payslip_pagibig.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("loans", payslip_loans.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("tardiness", payslip_tardiness.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("totalDeductions", payslip_totalDeductions.Text)
            report1.SetParameterValue("netPay", payslip_netPay.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Printer_Frm.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report1
        Printer_Frm.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

I tried every codes I know to convert these data to string type but nothing works. Is there another ways to get my required output for these? Thanks ^_^

Comment: I think the problem with your values and also .ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") will work when your object is datetime. So direct conversion from string to datetime, change the code to covert first in datetime and then append the format string.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is now solved. I use these codes `Dim inDate As String = Format(dgr.Cells(0).Value, "MM-dd-yyyy")` instead of these `Dim inDate As String = CStr(dgr.Cells(0).Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"))`. Thanks guys ^_^